# Configuring a Provider that returns a generic type in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, jdbi

I'm trying to set up a `Provider` for DAOs created using JDBI. JDBI uses a `Handle` object (which is a wrapper around a JDBC `Connection`) and you can get hold of a DAO by using `handle.attach(MyDaoType.class)`. Rather than having to write a separate `Provider` implementation for every DAO class I thought it would make sense to do this:

```
public class DaoProvider<T> implements Provider<T> {

  private final Class<T> daoType;
  private final Handle handle;

  @Injected 
  public DaoProvider(Class<T> daoType, Handle handle) {
    this.daoType = daoType;
    this.handle = handle;
  }

  @Override
  public T get() {
    return handle.attach(daoType);
  }
}
```

But it seems tremendously difficult to wire this up with Guice. I *have* tried using the `@Assisted` annotation on the 1st constructor argument as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8979127/565049). I defined a factory like this:

```
public interface DAOProviderFactory {
  <T> DAOProvider<T> create(Class<T> daoType);
}
```

But it's not clear how I should invoke the `FactoryModuleBuilder.implemented` method as the whole point is that I don't want to have to extend my provider class.

It also seems a bit crazy that I'd have a *factory* that returns a *provider* that returns the thing I actually want!

It strikes me that this would be really easy to do with the Spring DI container so I want to believe it's possible with Guice. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at this possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030609/how-do-i-pass-parameters-into-a-provider-with-guice

Comment: @condit that's enabled me to figure it out. Thanks. If you want to add an answer I'll accept it otherwise I'll post my solution later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @condit for pointing me at something that enabled me to solve the issue. It's actually very simple. I changed the `Provider` implementation to use field injection for the `Handler` like this:

```
public class DAOProvider<T> implements Provider<T> {

  private @Inject Handle handle;
  private final Class<T> daoType;

  public DAOProvider(Class<T> daoType) {
    this.daoType = daoType;
  }

  @Override public T get() {
    return handle.attach(daoType);
  }
}
```

Then in any module or application where I have specific DAO classes I want to bind I can just do something like this:

```
bind(UserStore.class).toProvider(new DAOProvider<>(UserStore.class));
bind(MessageStore.class).toProvider(new DAOProvider<>(MessageStore.class));
```

Guice then injects the `Handle` into the `DAOProvider` instances automatically.

Comment: Just as an aside - I'm not sure how you're managing the `Handle` but you may want to consider using the "on demand" method for retrieving your DAO. That way you wouldn't have to worry about the `Handle` not getting closed. You'd inject your `DBI` instead and then call `dbi.onDemand(daoType)` in your `get()` method.

Comment: @condit That's a very good idea, yes. I guess I was leaking handles all over the place. It's just a little demo app so didn't cause me any problems but worth thinking about anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this far too complicated. When you call the `get()` method, you are storing the result in a reference, which means you know the type of the particular DAO, which means you can write your code knowing the DAO class. I mean, think about how Guice itself works, you call `Injector.getInstance(Class<?> type)`... in other words, methods like this can't infer the type without you passing the `Class` anyway, so pass the `Class` when you use it!

I can understand why you might not want to inject `Handle` directly though, so why not just make a wrapper, e.g.

```
public interface DaoProvider {
  <T> T provideDao(Class<T> daoType);
}
```

And then:

```
public class JdbiDaoProvider implements DaoProvider {
  private final Handle handle;

  @Inject
  JdbiDaoProvider(Handle handle) {
    this.handle = handle;
  }

  public <T> T provideDao(Class<T> daoType) {
    return handle.attach(daoType);
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems to me to have no advantage of just injecting a `Handle` and using `handle.attach()` wherever I need a DAO. That's okay I guess but I was hoping I'd be able to just inject a `UserDAO` or whatever directly and Guice should be able to provide one. That simplifies the code in every component that needs to use a DAO.